# How do I extract the labels from a MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just trying to extract info contained in a multiindex into a series or array.  Not sure if this is a pandas specific question or just a question of extracting attributes from a python object.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'id' : np.arange(99,105) / 3,
                     'yr' : np.tile( np.array([2007,2008,2009]), 2 ),
                     'val': np.random.randn(6) } )

In [131]: df.set_index(['id','yr']).index

Out[131]: MultiIndex(levels=[[33, 34], [2007, 2008, 2009]],
                     labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
                     names=[u'id', u'yr'])
```

That is, I just want to extract the following info into an array or series:

`labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]`

The following code will get the values, but I want the labels:

```
In [130]: df.set_index(['id','yr']).index.get_values()

Out[130]: array([(33, 2007), (33, 2008), (33, 2009), (34, 2007), (34, 2008), (34, 2009)], dtype=object)
```

There are some other 'get' methods of multiindex but I can't get any of them to do what I want (and am not sure if any of them does what I need anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can tell, `df.index` gives you a dictionary-like object that stores values under keywords.

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[33, 34], [2007, 2008, 2009]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=[u'id', u'yr'])
```

The keywords being `levels`, `labels`, `names`. You can access these separately through

```
df.index.labels
```

which gives

```
FrozenList([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

and similarly for the others.

Comment: Thanks!  I could have sworn that was the fist thing I tried, but I must have typed it in wrong and then I started looking for much more complicated answers...